# Where to store user uploaded pictures on a single server

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, image-uploading

I have seen many questions concerning the storage of user uploaded image files onto a web application, but most of these are dealing with the following:

- Indexing of the images, so as to retrieve them later
- How to store them (on the server itself as a file or in the database)

I have a question in regards to this subject, but the question is:

**In what directory do I put the uploaded image file? (or other file type, for that matter)**

I have a small group I am running php apps for. There is very little files that get uploaded, but nontheless, they get uploaded.

I currently have them in my public html document root under `/var/www/images/*` , however I am told that it is not smart to store your user uploaded content straight to the `/var/www/*` directory and that it should be stored elsewhere.

However I cannot find a straightforward statement of where "elsewhere" is.

Keep in mind I do not have a server farm where I can establish certain servers for specific purposes (such as uploaded user files).

Therefore, on a single webserver that hosts usual scripting files, etc. **what is the best storage practice for such content?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's necessarily a 'best practice' per se; **anywhere** on your server will be fine, so long as you're able to retrieve the images later on. Typically they'd go inside a folder under `/var/www/images/`.

Personally I'd recommend creating an **individual** folder to store these user-uploaded images in (as something like `/var/www/images/user_uploads`), so that they don't get confused with other images you might have uploaded directly to `/var/www/images/` (such as backgrounds or core imagery).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to access anything from the outside world that is not under `/var/www/*`? In other words, is there even any "other" location in a single webserver set up? Or am I only left with `/var/www/*` anyway? I guess that is my main question.

Comment: In terms of users actually uploading files, you're restricted to `var/www`. You're free to create whatever folder you'd like in there though; it doesn't necessarily have to be in `/images` (though it would make sense).

Comment: **anywhere** is fine, depends on your requirement. for most of times, put it under `/images` within your website directory is an ok approach. though people will start arguing if you consider security, scalability, and much more. for a single site, is ok, just be sure that user uploads image, not another php script. happy coding, nonetheless.